# Navigation doesn't sit on one line or align

Tags: html, css

I think it should be quite clear what I'm trying to do with this: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/6BHW6/9/

I want it all aligned on one line, and with the name and arrow aligned to the right of the bar. I believe I have put the right code in place for this but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

- I did `align: right` for the name and arrow and yet they don't show
- I did `display: inline-block` for the `ul` but it doesn't stay on one line

Can anyone please show me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: can you please rephrase the question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6BHW6/16/ check out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the **li** that you want to display inline, not the **ul**:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I mean the very right of the bar, it's going to obviously appear on the right **of the list** because it's the last 2 elements in the `li` list, but OP wanted it on the **right of the nav bar**

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BHW6/10/)

Add a new `ul` with the elements you want on  the right.

```
<header>
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">&#9660;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul> 
</header>
```

Give the top one a class of `right`, like you wanted.

The `li` element is the one you want to display `inline-block;`